# What battle did the German and US join forces in WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany

I remember learning about a battle towards the end of WW2 when some German and American forces fought side by side.

What was that Battle?

and

Were they both fighting against the SS?

Comment: [The Battle for Castle Itter](https://www.history.co.uk/articles/the-day-germans-and-americans-fought-side-by-side-during-ww2). Also on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Castle_Itter). Given the numbers involved, it probably should be considered a skirmish rather than a battle.

Comment: @KillingTime Yes, indeed and it seems there was a second.:[Battle of Castle Itter - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Castle_Itter) and [Operation Cowboy - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Cowboy). This would be a base for an answer.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Is 'Cowboy' already explicated on this site? (If not, then an answer dealing with it )is probably missing?

Comment: @LаngLаngС Since the topic of [Battle of Castle Itter](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/41478/38607) has been handled in that answer, *Operation Cowboy* could be added as second sample.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Seems to me: this Q, and the other Q demand an addition of that. Whether as full A or edit? Your choice… But I heard of 'Cowboy' just now: so, perhaps a full post? Esp to complement this 'dupe'?

Comment: @LаngLаngС As an addendum at the bottom of the existing answer would be better, keeping the 2 existing samples togeather.